# Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2, In WO Listing page to display value and description in same column

Tags: maximo-anywhere

How to Display value and description in same column in WO Listing page,

Example: ZIST-  Device Installation for OPC and LPC

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new local Attribute to your Workorder Resource, and I would recommend that you populate it in the onInitialize() method of that object.  Then add that local attribute to the workorder list like any other attribute.  Take a look at how we do this with assetnum and assetdescription in our existing code.

```
onInitialize : function(workOrder) {
            workOrder.set("locationdesc", workOrder.get('maxlocationdesc'));



            if(workOrder.get('assetdesc')==null){
                workOrder.set("assetnumanddescription",'');

            }

            workOrder.set("assetdesc", workOrder.get('maxassetdesc'));

            if(workOrder.get('locationdesc')==null){
                workOrder.set("locationanddescription",'');

            }

            fieldUtil.initCompositeField("wonum", "description", "wonumanddescription", workOrder);
            fieldUtil.initCompositeField("asset", "assetdesc", "assetnumanddescription", workOrder);
            fieldUtil.initCompositeField("location", "locationdesc", "locationanddescription", workOrder);
```